# How to connect Test application in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a beginner of objective c. I created unit test application. How am I call test method?
Bellow given my sample code. 
my project ::

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    int a=25;
    int b=25;

    MyUnitTestTests *myValue;
    if ([myValue respondsToSelector:@selector(testExample:testExample:)])
    {
      int c =  [myValue testExample:25 testExample:10];
       NSLog(@"value %i",c);
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Test method ::

```
- (int)testExample:(int )a testExample:(int )b
{
    int c= a+b;
    return c;    
}
```

is there any error ??
I tried lot of time to do this simple test. but output was (value 0)

Comment: replace `MyUnitTestTests *myValue;` with this line `MyUnitTestTests *myValue = [[MyUnitTestTests alloc]init];`

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: what is `MyUnitTestTests` here?

Comment: yes : 
Two errors occurred 01:) Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyUnitTestTests", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o  02).ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: In my Program no any compile and runtime errors. but when I show View --> Navigaters --> Show Log Navigator. show those errors. is there any wrong ?

Comment: did you add `#import MyUnitTestTests.h` in your viewController class?

Comment: Yes. It added to ViewConroller.h file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23281/discussion-between-gayan-and-pratyusha-terli)

Comment: @Gayan You've tagged this with "unit-testing" and "ocunit" but I don't see anything that resembles an OCUnit unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Your output is not correct

```
NSLog(@"value %d", c);
```

Thus, without `%i` and with `%d` it should be correct.

And there is another bug: the instance `myValue` was not initialized.

```
MyUnitTestTests *myValue = [[MyUnitTestTests alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thnks , but still value was 0.

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint on `int c =  [myValue testExample:25 testExample:10];`? You could inspect the value of `myValue` which should not be `nil` and perhaps step into the testExample method

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typing int c =  [myValue testExample:25 testExample:10];

Just type [self testExample:25 testExample:10];

And print the log statement in your test method.